# Is $\{e^{2\sqrt{2}k\pi i}|k\in\mathbb{Z} \}$ closed?

Tags: general-topology, complex-analysis

Is $\{e^{2\sqrt{2}k\pi i }|k\in\mathbb{Z} \}$ closed? And do these points all lie on a circle? This looks simple but for some reason, I cannot figure out the answers. Thank you

Comment: You must have tried something?

Comment: @Math_QED First, I thought this being countable means it is closed. But it is clearly wrong

Comment: This question could help you : https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1569152/dense-set-in-the-unit-circle-reference-needed?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: @peterag Thank you for pointing it out. I edited the question

Comment: @Heisenberg After this edition, it is trivial that your set is $S^1$, which is closed. Is this really what you meant?

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos Oh wow I messed this up. Let me edit this. This is not what I meant

Comment: I edited the question again. There should not have been a t in the first place

Answer (score 2):

The (bilateral) sequence $\{e^{2\sqrt{2}\pi k i}\}_{k\in\mathbb{Z}}$ is dense in the unit circle since $\sqrt{2}$ is irrational.
If the set of elements of such sequence were closed, it would be the whole unit circle, but no element of the sequence equals $-1$, for instance.

Answer (score 2):

Every point of your set belongs to $S^1$. Since $\sqrt2\pi$ irrational, it follows from [Dirichlet's approximation theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet%27s_approximation_theorem) that it is a dense subset of $S^1$. Therefore, it is not closed.

Answer (score 1):

The points indeed lie on the circle within the complex plane, since $|e^{\theta i}| = 1$ for any $\theta \in \Bbb R$.

The set is not closed.  In fact, we can show that the closure $\overline{\{e^{2\sqrt{2}k\pi i }|k\in\mathbb{Z} \}}$ is the entire unit circle with an argument along [these lines](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2217717/prove-that-x-y-are-positive-real-x-y-is-irrational-then-the-set-mxny/2217749#2217749).  That is, we want to show that $\{\langle \sqrt{2}\,m \rangle : m \in \Bbb Z\}$ is dense in the interval $[0,1]$.

Comment: Oh wow this is brilliant. Thank you for the reference as well

Comment: What do you mean by $<>$ symbol?

Comment: @DonaldEdwards $\langle x \rangle = x - \lfloor x \rfloor$