# Let $f:\Bbb N^2\to\Bbb R:(m,n)\mapsto a^mb^n$, with $0<a<1<b$. Is $\operatorname{im}\! f$ dense in $\Bbb R_{>0}$?

Tags: real-analysis, reference-request, real-numbers

Given real $a$ and $b$ with $0<a<1<b$, can every positive real number be arbitrarily well approximated by a number of the form $a^mb^n$ ($m,n\in\Bbb N$), provided that $a^mb^n=1$ only when $m=n=0\,$?

I expect this problem to be well known but am unable to find it by a web search.

Comment: This question is equivalent to asking whether the numbers $\{m\log a+n\log b\}$ are dense in $\Bbb R$, and the "provided that" condition is equivalent to stipulating that $\log a$ and $\log b$ are linearly independent over $\Bbb Q$. At this point the fact that $\log a$ and $\log b$ are logarithms is no longer crucial, and one can search on the group spanned by a set of two linearly independent real numbers.

Comment: Since $m,n$ are restricted to be natural numbers, it isn’t true for two positive linearly independent reals. So the equivalent is given two real numbers of opposite sign and linearly independent over $\mathbb Q,$ … @greg

Comment: Another way to rephrase it is that the condition requires that $\alpha=\log_b(1/a)$ is positive and irrational. Then this is equivalent to saying $$S=\{m\alpha-n\mid m,n\in\mathbb N\}$$ is dense in $\mathbb R,$ since $(1/b)^{m\alpha-n}=a^mb^n.$ You can actually show that $S$ is dense in $\mathbb R$ for any irrational $\alpha.$

Comment: Thanks, @ThomasAndrews . If you post your comment as an answer, then I can accept it.

Comment: More generally, given any $S\subseteq \mathbb R$ which contains $0,$ a negative and positive number, and is closed under addition, is either dense in $\mathbb R$ it is equal to $r\mathbb Z$ for some real $r.$

Comment: I suspect this has been asked and answered before, and this question doesn’t match requirements for a “good question,” since no work has been shown, so custom here is to not answer.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews : Yes, thanks to your comment, I can see that the question is equivalent to [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2217717/prove-that-x-y-are-positive-real-x-y-is-irrational-then-the-set-mxny?rq=1), which has been well answered.